# What is the recommended disk size for Windows Server Standard 2012 R2 Core Installation?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I could only find the full version, 127GB.  How big should a disk be for just a core installation, not using all the Roles, mostly just IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 GB is the minimum.

> Be aware that 32 GB should be considered an absolute minimum value for successful installation. This minimum should allow you to install
>   Windows Server 2012 R2 in Server Core mode, with the Web Services
>   (IIS) server role. A server in Server Core mode is about 4 GB smaller
>   than the same server in Server with a GUI mode. For the smallest
>   possible installation footprint, start with a Server Core installation
>   and then completely remove any server roles or features you do not
>   need by using Features on Demand. For more information about Server
>   Core and Minimal Server Interface modes, see Windows Server
>   Installation Options.
>
> The system partition will need extra space for any of the following
>   circumstances:
>
> If you install the system over a network.
>
> Computers with more than 16 GB of RAM will require more disk space for
>   paging, hibernation, and dump files.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303418(v=ws.11).aspx